# Logging in Local time in Metrolog

Tags: uwp, metrolog

My Metrolog output looks like its being logged in GMT. My timezone is GMT +5.30. The time is set correctly on the device. How can I make Metrolog to log in local time?

Example Log: `4|2017-05-15T05:05:36.6887812+00:00|TRACE|3|App|Analytics configured`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the trace layout by creating a class extending *MetroLog.Layouts.Layout*, in which you can display the **DateTime** according to your timezone :

```
public class CustomLayout : MetroLog.Layouts.Layout
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a formatted string based on given informations
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"><see cref="LogWriteContext"/></param>
    /// <param name="info"><see cref="LogEventInfo"/></param>
    /// <returns>Formatted string to log</returns>
    public override string GetFormattedString(LogWriteContext context, LogEventInfo info)
    {
        return $"{info.SequenceID}|{info.TimeStamp.LocalDateTime}|{info.Level}|{info.Logger}|{info.Message}|{info.Exception}";
    }
}
```

And don't forget to use this custom layout when initializing your target. For instance, if you're using a **DebugTarget**, you should do something like :

```
var loggingConfiguration = new LoggingConfiguration { IsEnabled = true };
loggingConfiguration.AddTarget(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, new DebugTarget(new CustomLayout()));
```

And then create your log manager :

```
var logManager = LogManagerFactory.CreateLogManager(loggingConfiguration);
```